# Is it possible to return resolved value from promise without async/await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, apollo

I am following apollo tutorials (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/resolvers/) and I saw this code:

```
me: async (_, __, { dataSources }) =>
  dataSources.userAPI.findOrCreateUser()
```

Because `dataSources.userAPI.findOrCreateUser()` returns **Promise**, I thought 
that `await dataSources.userAPI.findOrCreateUser()` was right.

But it working really well without any errors and I got resolved value in React... even this below code working well too.

```
me: (_, __, { dataSources }) =>
  dataSources.userAPI.findOrCreateUser()
```

This code makes me confused. How does it work?

Comment: You only need `async` if you're going to: 1. `await` something; or 2. return a non-promise value that you want to be wrapped in a promise. If you're already returning a promise, it doesn't matter whether or not the function is `async`, the result is the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh...i got it...thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Besides enabling `await`, `async` [implicitly wraps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_await_promiseValue_vs._return_promiseValue) the result of the function into a `Promise.resolve()`. Roughly:

```
async function() {
  return something;
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
function() {
  return Promise.resolve(something);
}
```

The thing is `Promise.resolve()` "flattens" its argument, meaning if its argument is a *thenable* (such as another Promise) it automatically "resolves" to it. In other words, `Promise.resolve(somethingThatIsAPromise).then(<work>)` has the same effect of `somethingThatIsAPromise.then(<work>)`.

[MDN tries to explain that behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) (bold is mine):

> The `Promise.resolve()` method returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object that is resolved
>   with a given value. **If the value is a promise, that promise is
>   returned**; if the value is a thenable (i.e. has a ["`then`" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)), the
>   returned promise will **"follow"** that thenable, adopting its eventual
>   state; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the
>   value. This function **flattens** nested layers of promise-like objects
>   (e.g. a promise that resolves to a promise that resolves to something)
>   into a single layer.

And, since what your arrow functions returns (`dataSources.userAPI.findOrCreateUser()`) is a Promise, due to that "flattening", having `async` or not ends up in the same behavior.

Comment: really thanks. i haven't known that until now... thanks for letting me know that useful info!